# Is the use of package name only limited to directory structure and in app references?

Tags: android

The naming convention is usually `company.domain.inreverse.appname` 
Is there a significance of using the actual company domain

Asking because I by mistake named the package `com.companyName.app.appName` instead of `in.co.companyName.app.appName` (where the company's actual internet domain is companyName.co.in)

So would it in any way affect my app, and/or its relation to the website?

Answer (score 0):

No.. it won't. The idea is to give Global uniqueness.

check this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions

```
The Java Language Specification establishes package naming conventions to avoid the possibility of two published packages having the same name.
```

But keep in mind this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

```
Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.
```